# Escape html and markdown in flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to escape the HTML as well as markdown at the same time in flask. I have tried `|safe` filter but it only escapes HTML tags but don't escape markdown. I have also tried Markdown function from flask and pass it to the template like this:

```py
from flask import Markup

@app.route('/my-route')
def my_route():
    text = Markup('Some markup text here')

    return render_template('myroute.html', text=text)
```

And then pass text in my template. But that too doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily escape markdown since it's simply text with special characters.

However, if you want to escape `<html> <\html>` blocks, you can take a look at the `<xmp>` tag. By the documentation

> The HTML Example Element () renders text between the start and end tags without interpreting the HTML in between and using a monospaced font

If you convert your markdown to html an you want to print that html, you can do:

```
<xmp>
  <p> This will be displayed as pure HTML code<p>
</xmp>
```

**Output**

```
<p> This will be displayed as pure HTML code<p>
```

Comment: I have read that `<xmp>` tag was deprecated from HTML 3.2 and later. Also I am able to escape HTML tags easily with `|safe' filter. You have also said that >You can easily escape markdown since it's simply text with special characters. But How to do that?

Comment: Markdown is simply text, say `**this is bold text**`. If you don't parse the markdown into html and print it in python you should get the `**this is bold text**`. However, I would recommend you use a node module instead, which is more complex than what Flask offers. The module is `showdown` https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

Comment: I know basic javascript but not comfortable nor interested in using node. Any other solution? Isn't there any filter like `|safe` for markdown?